# making a footer stay at the bottom of a page using css

Tags: css

Below I have some HTML code. Everything is positioned relative apart from contentRow which is positioned absolutely. This is making the footer stick to where the browser window ends and not where the scroll bar ends.

Is there any way I can make the footer go down to the very bottom where the scroll bar ends.

```
<div id="s4-workspace" style="width: 1920px; height: 748px; overflow:scroll">
    <div id="s4-bodyContainer" style="position:relative">   

        <div class="headerSection" style="position:relative">           
            <div class="globalHeader">             
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div>          
            <div id="contentRow" style="position:relative">
                <div class="fixedWidthMain" style="position:relative">   
                         <div class="fixedWidthMain" style="position:absolute">   

                </div>           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--PAGE FOOTER SECTION-->
    <div class="pageFooterSection" style="clear: both;position:relative">      

    </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Google "sticky footer"

Comment: I don't want the footer to stick at the bottom.I just want it to be below the main content area .

Comment: That is exactly what a sticky footer does, it will stay at the bottom of the page despite the amount of html content.

Comment: I ve updated the question to show my issue exactly.As soon as I put position absolute the footer comes up and site til the browser window and not to the scroll bar at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few available flavours of the solution for this but they basically go something like this.

**EXAMPLE**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

a point to remember is that height of elements in html are always passed through the parent. so if you dont define height 100% on a parent the child won't know either. Good luck and let me know if you have any other issues :)

**SOURCE**

http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could make s4-bodyContainer position:relative so that the contentRow is only positioned absolutely within that container.  Then footer would go below the bodyContainer.